# Is there official Figma file with all real components for Angular Material version 14?

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, figma

We are currently developing a web application using Angular 14, which requires the use of Angular Material 14. To facilitate our design process, I was wondering if Figma UI Kits for Angular Material components are available and published anywhere.

I managed to find the following Figma file (https://www.figma.com/community/file/1292454516527463513), but it is tagged as beta, and I'm uncertain if it meets our requirements.

Is there a central location where I can access the latest Figma designs for the most recent major versions of the Angular Material component kit?

Thank you in advance!